# Elif processing on serverside

Tags: python, json, mongodb, gis, tornado

i've a question that breaks my head;

i'll make an e-commerce site using MongoDB and Python (Tornado), and i'll use the GIS to suggests some products to users near that region, and i've a lot of cities, for exalmpe, a departement X will have Y cities, i'll use Javascript to hide the other cities when the user choses a departement; and every city, i've got their coordinates using google maps (really a headache), and those coordinates will not be seen by users, it's only used for products suggestions, so here is my problem:

- bezcause i'll use only one collection in mongodb, i'll nest documents (user profil and cart) because i'll not let them modify their profile, it's an ecommerce after all, so to trust people, i'll try to let them "have only one personality" maybe they can delete and create another one, but this, it's another problem.
  and because of that, i dont want to create another collection of cities, so can i make another tip to handle the coordinates to let them be tied to each city? for exemple if a person chooses that he lives in Algiers (Algeria), he will get directly (Lat, Long) coordinates that i've already saved from internet, if i'll use "elif", this will make a lot of time to process all that data (approximatively 300 cities), and what about using a separate json file that contains a departement, a city, and its coordinates?

Comment: So, what's the question exactly?

Comment: does using a lot of elif (300) will "kill" the server, is there any other solution?
because i'll make something lik if city=algiers: coordinates=(x, y)elif city = annaba: ....

Comment: As you mention MongoDB - check out the Geo2D indexing, and maybe JQuery autocomplete with AJAX for display/searching...

Comment: Sounds like you need a MongoDB collection that stores a city ID, name, coordinates, and whatever else you might need. Also this sounds like you brainstorming rather than an actual question.

Comment: @jozzas: i'll see about Geo2D, and about the second solution,
the document will have only one ID: the cart ID and user ID, i dont want to make it complicated with joints, neither make a long collection, the bandwidth here is not good, this is why i'll try to avoid joints, and long server processing

Comment: You're already using MongoDB. It shouldn't complicate things very much to keep your data organised in a database!

Comment: yes, this is why i want to make a collection of 2 documents (nested) one for the product, and the other for the client nested in the product, it is denormalized, but the database is only for reading and not updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a dictionary?

```
city = "Houston"
coordinates = {"Houston": (26.35, 57.12),
          "Las Vegas": (27.34, 35.23),
          etc...}
coords = coordinates[city]
```

Seems like an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Even better, put it in a database with a city ID that can then be associated with businesses and people.

Comment: Good point. I was just showing a quick example for the sake of simplicity though. Dont think OP knew about dicts, and databases are more complicated.

Comment: so the solution is to using a tuple? :o

Comment: The solution is to use a dictionary that contains tuples :)

Comment: why dident i think about that :'(
thank you ;)
but, how do i get the statement??

Comment: ok, am dumb :p a dictionnary, if we input the key, then the value will follow the key :D
sorry and thank you again :p